# Can anyone point me to any resouce that describes how seaborn bins the data based on x-axis values in seaborn.regplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, seaborn

This is the documentation of seaborn x_bins of [seaborn.regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)-

> **x_bins: int or vector, optional**
>
> Bin the x variable into discrete bins and then estimate the central tendency and a confidence interval. This binning only influences how the scatterplot is drawn; the regression is still fit to the original data. This parameter is interpreted either as the number of evenly-sized (not necessarily spaced) bins or the positions of the bin centers. When this parameter is used, it implies that the default of x_estimator is NumPy.mean.

I am unclear of this line "This parameter is interpreted either as the number of evenly-sized (not necessary spaced) bins or the positions of the bin centers. " A simple example will be highly appreciated

Comment: When all else fails, you could check the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn).

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/regression.py#L318) points to a function `bin_predictor`. When `x_bins` is set, all x-values are grouped into the given number of bins. This only influences the x-positions of the scatter plot; the regression line is still calculated using the original values.

Note that the x-positions for binning are calculated such that each bin corresponds (more or less) to the same number of original points. The x-positions usually aren't spaced evenly. This can be helpful to better understand a huge dataset. (The calculation uses an even spacing into the percentiles to choose the x-positions for the centers.)

Here is some code and a plot to show the effect:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(16, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax, xbins in zip(axs, [None, 2, 4, 10]):
    sns.regplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', y='sepal_length', x_bins=xbins, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'x_bins={xbins}')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: effect of x_bins on sns.regplot]

Here is another example, using the `geyser` dataset. The `x_bins` parameter helps in assessing how useful a line regression is for fitting the data.

[image: sns.regplot with geyser dataset and x_bins]